# Why does JDialog 'jump' on setLocationRelativeTo()?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Have a class that extends JDialog. It's initialized entirely on EDT (just in case).
Now,

```
public PropsDialog (JFrame parentFrame)
{
    super(parentFrame);
    // boring
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
    setVisible(true);
}
```

results in dialog appearing in the leftmost corner and then jumping to it's intended position.
Am I doing smth wrong?

Comment: What happens when you call pack() after setLocationRelativeTo()?

Comment: Jumps from the very same corner and ends up not correctly centered against the parent frame (which is correct). Seems like a bug as I'm getting this behavior on built-in LaFs only. Synth works as expected.

Comment: How about calling setVisible(false) just before setLocationRelativeTo()?

Comment: Really appreciate your effort. Thanks. Unfortunately, that doesn't change a thing. I think I'll end up checking on different JDKs under Win, Linux & Mac to see if the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide a working example and more information? For example, on what operating system are you testing on? Swing has some differences between some, e.g. JDialogs without a parent getting an entry in the gnome panel but not in the windows taskbar and things like that.

Secondly, I would guess, that your JDialog is visible before you call setLocationRelativeTo, maybe through somewhat within the part you commented out as "boring". I would suggest, you punch a quick

```
System.out.println(isVisible());
```

into your code, just before setLocationRelativeTo, just in case...

Comment: You were close :).
Refactoring the dialog to extend JDialog, i missed out the show() call on it. This method previously fired a call to JOptionPane that in turn displayed a JDialog and been removed during refactoring. But as class extends JDialog now, the show() call actually sets it visible.